# Is the concatenation operation on a list associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction, recursion, big-list

Is the concatenation operation on a list associative?

```
[] = empty list
l and l' = lists
```

Let's assume that we have to prove that:

```
l concat (l' concat []) = (l concat l') concat []
```

How can I prove it using a prof by induction?

I was thinking that:
base case is: `[] concat l' = l'`
Step case  is = `(s:l) concat l' = l'`

I am not sure if what I wrote is correct and if the base and step cases are correct.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean l' is a list?

Comment: I've modified the formatting a bit. Please let me know if it doesn't fit your intended meaning.

Comment: yes l' ( l prime) is a list

Comment: By using the same letter the symbol `l'` suggest some correlation to `l`. Wouldn't is be more clear if you name your lists with different letters, say, `l` and `k`?

Comment: @CiaPan yes you are right, and then how can I go on?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way to prove that concatenation is associative is using indices: prove that if $a,b,c$ are lists and $i$ is an index, then
$$((a\ \mathrm{concat}\ b)\ \mathrm {concat}\ c)[i]=(a\ \mathrm{concat}\ (b\ \mathrm {concat}\ c))[i]$$
Proving it this way does not require induction.

Comment: Um, why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't find this answer useful either. What your post amounts to saying is "prove that the concatenation product is associative". I don't see a method and I don't see how to prove the statement without induction.